# How to grow these CSS grid cells to their content?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In theory, CSS grid cells should grow to accommodate larger content. How to achieve that in the below example? When I shrink the window, the blue boxes stick out of the white ones.

```css
body{
    background: lightgrey;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
}

.subscription-items {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 8%;
}

.subscription-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

.subscription-item-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.subscription-item-price {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="subscriptions">            
            <div class="subscription-items">
              <div class="subscription-item">                  
                  <a class="subscription-item-btn product-type-full" type="button">
                    <span class="subscription-item-price" id="monthly-price">12 345,67 EUR</span>
                    <span class="subscription-item-length"> / month </span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="subscription-item subscription-item-yearly">
                    <a class="subscription-item-btn product-type-full" type="button">
                        <span class="subscription-item-price" id="yearly-price">12 345,67 EUR</span>
                        <span class="subscription-item-length"> / year </span>
                    </a>                    
                </div>
                <div class="subscription-item">
                    <a class="subscription-item-btn subscription-item-restore-btn" type="button">
                        Restore
                    </a>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: also https://jsfiddle.net/5ey6n90d/

Answer (score 1):

```
.subscription-item-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 13px;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
    min-width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

remove `white-space`

Comment: Please take the time to explain how and why this helps, and how it applies in the situation described in the original question. This then assists people with learning rather than just having the answer to this very specific instance.

Comment: The nowrap is intentional, as I don't want it to wrap.